# Syntax error on selecting from sub-query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

Getting syntax error while executing the following query?

```
select *
    from (select row_number() over (order by title) as RowNum  from question)
    where RowNum>5
```

Anyone knows how to get it fixed?

Comment: Please make sure you post *Error message* to get accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give `ALIAS` to sub-query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY title) AS RowNum  FROM question) AS t1
WHERE RowNum>5
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you selected the COLUMNS from the TABLE in the subquery, no?

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by title) as RowNum
    from question) SQ
where RowNum > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE AS
(

    select row_number() over (order by title) as RowNum  from question
)
select * 
From Cte
Where RowNum > 5
```

OR

```
Select * From
(select row_number() over (order by title) as RowNum  from question)X
Where X.RowNum > 5
```